# Does JavaScript var expression return undefined?

Tags: javascript

Does the JavaScript expression will return something?

In the Node.js REPL:

```
> console.log("Hello World")
Hello World
undefined
```

the `undefined` is the JavaScript function return. Because the JavaScript function always return something.

But when I try define a variable in REPL:

```
> var x = 11
undefined
```

There will print a `undefined` too. whether the JavaScript var expression will return something too?

Comment: the undefined is the result of calling console.log ... it's what console.log returns

Comment: @JaromandaX I mean the `var x = 11`.

Comment: what is "the javaScript express" ? Is that a train that is first stop Javascript?

Comment: yes ... well, the result of `var x` is `undefined`

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: ahhh . you mean **expression**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all JavaScript statements have a result, although often it's pretty much useless, and only available using `eval` function - at least until [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) will be added to the language. For example.

```
>>> eval("if (true) 4; else 5;")
4
>>> eval("if (true) 4; else 5;")
5
>>> eval("for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) 7")
7
>>> eval("for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}")
undefined
>>> eval("var express = 4")
undefined
```

And so on, the exact values are specified in a language specification.

Comment: It should be called "result" or something. A *return value* is only something a `return` statement can produce

Comment: @Bergi fixed, thanks for noticing - by the way, you can edit posts, although you probably know about this already

Comment: Sure, I've done a few thousand edits already :-) I only fix syntax errors or typos without commenting though, not content, at least in posts of new users.

Answer (score 0):

When you type something in either browser's console or Node.js REPL, the expression in enclosed in IIFE and executed. This IIFE returns the expression that you entered. So if your expression is not returning anything, it prints `undefined`.

Imagine you typed:

```
console.log(1)
```

It is interpreted by Node.js REPL as:

```
(function() { return console.log(1) })()
```

Since it is not returning anything, it simply prints `undefined` on console.

Now if you write a number (e.g. `1`) in REPL, it is interpreted as:

```
(function() { return 1 })()
```

This will print `1` as return value.

HTH